# How to properly fetch a custom album from PHAssetCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, phphotolibrary

I've created a custom album now I am attempting to download a video from an FTP site and move it to the custom album.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin C# ios 11.4.
Permissions set in Info.plist
Prior to this block, I am testing to verify the user is Authorized to access the photo library.

This is my first time using PHPhotoLibrary and I can't find many C# code samples.

No error generated, just crashes at the line beginning PHFetchReult fetchResult.

UPDATED
Found this in log on my iPad.

Date/Time:       2018-06-25 18:05:54 -0400
   OS Version:      iPhone OS 11.4.1 (Build 15G5072a)
   Architecture:    arm64
   Report Version:  26

Data Source:     KPerf Lightweight PET
Kernel Cache:    0xffffffe000000000 07AF39CA-659D-3636-4A4A-FE05631AA416
Reason:          UIKit-runloop-AppStore: timeout 816ms

Command:         AppStore
Path:            /Applications/AppStore.app/AppStore
Identifier:      com.apple.AppStore
Version:         3.0 (1)
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             4415

Duration:        0.80s
Steps:           16 (50ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  J71AP
Active cpus:     2

```
private PHAssetCollection FindAlbum(string title)
{
    PHAssetCollection photoAlbum = null;

    var fetchOptions = new PHFetchOptions() { Predicate = 
        NSPredicate.FromFormat(string.Format("title={0}", title)) };
    PHFetchResult fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.FetchAssetCollections(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, options: fetchOptions); 

    if (fetchResult.firstObject != null)
    {
        photoAlbum = (PHAssetCollection)fetchResult.firstObject;
    }
    return photoAlbum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what is going on and how to resolve it though I don't fully understand why the object doesn't return a null but instead crashes, perhaps this is a bug.

In the end, the issue was that the Predicate wasn't being passed properly.  I also paired down the search to include subtype of only RegularAlbums since I am looking specifically for a custom album.

Hope this helps someone else in the C# world out :)

```
   private PHAssetCollection FindAlbum(string title)
    {
        PHAssetCollection photoAlbum = null;
        var arguments = new NSObject[] { NSObject.FromObject( title) };
        var fetchOptions = new PHFetchOptions() { Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("title=%@", arguments) };

        PHFetchResult fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.FetchAssetCollections(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, PHAssetCollectionSubtype.AlbumRegular, fetchOptions);

        if (fetchResult.firstObject != null)
        {
            photoAlbum = (PHAssetCollection)fetchResult.firstObject;

        }
        return photoAlbum;
    }
```